# In this SQL example is the usage of INTERVAL correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to track down a bug where the `next` column is not being updated with a date in the future.

Is my usage of adding INTERVAL to the `next` column correct?

```
UPDATE 
    `delay_shorts` AS `DelayShort`  
    SET 
        `DelayShort`.`delta` = 1, 
        `DelayShort`.`next` = '2002-04-14 21:31:01' + INTERVAL 5 SECOND, 
        `DelayShort`.`last_changed` = '2002-04-14 21:31:01'  
    WHERE `DelayShort`.`id` = 3
```

Comment: I'd rather - for personal philosophy - use the proper `DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT('2002-04-14 21:31:01', '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)`

Comment: It is in that it works for me.

Comment: It is valid. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7559

Comment: thanks guys. My problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `INTERVAL` expression is used in [`DATE_ADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) or [`DATE_SUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) functions:

```
UPDATE 
    `delay_shorts` AS `DelayShort`  
    SET 
        `DelayShort`.`next` = DATE_ADD('2002-04-14 21:31:01', INTERVAL 5 SECOND) 
    WHERE `DelayShort`.`id` = 3
```

It's important to note that the units of `INTERVAL` are *always* expressed in singular form: although you're adding 5 *second**s***, you express it as `5 SECOND`.

Comment: The `INTERVAL` expression is perfectly valid when used directly with a DATE/DATETIME column, absent `DATE_ADD(),DATE_SUB()`.  The OP's usage is valid. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7558

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That's a surprise to me. Looks like a good competitive answer, no?